# Android - how I can I achieve location accuracy in Google Map

Tags: android, geolocation, android-wifi

I am self learning Android programming at the moment. I was about to write app that will display my location on map without using GPS.

I have tried using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and found that my accuracy is constantly at 2000 even in city area with a lot of wifi around the area.

I would like to know how could other map application (e.g. GoogleMap) is able to achieve high accuracy without using GPS.

Answer (score 0):

They use GPS.  Or they lie about their accuracy.  Ever seen the big blue circle around your position in Google Maps?  That means they think you're somewhere in that circle, and are guessing about actual position.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get accuracy is to use GPS/GLONASS signals. A-GPS can help to fix position quickly because it provides info about which satellites are in view from your phone cell position (your device don't spend time trying to get signals from satellites not in view).

The 'High accuracy' mode is just a lie from Google to know your position all the time to monetize you in perverse ways

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the network provider to fetch the location they are not very accurate. SO its not a good idea to fetch the accuracy of your position using
network provider. Its best to use GPS to get the location updates. You can use GetAccuracy() method of Location class and see for the value it returns. 
Let Say if  getAccuracy() retruns 25 then you can leave this value wait for another gps value which is more accurate.